# Validation library for PHP/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, validation

Is there any lightweight validation library available for PHP that easily can check if a specific string or value is valid for a known database type -

Something like this:

```
 if (is_MEDIUMINT($var)) {
      $this->db->insert($anothervar);
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: No one that knows of this? I cant be the first one to think that this might come handy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) database is part of the ANSI 2003 specification, so you could use that across any DB vendor that supports it (MySQL, Postgresql, SQLite, MSSQL 2k5+).

```
/*public static*/ function is_dbtype($table, $column, $type) {
    $db = (...)::getInstance(); // assuming PDO
    $sql = 'SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS '.
        'WHERE TABLE_NAME = :table AND COLUMN_NAME = :column';
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute(array(':table' => $table, ':column' => $column));
    return ($type == $st->fetchColumn());
}
```

Change COLUMN_TYPE to DATA_TYPE if you just want "varchar" instead of "varchar(64)".  If you need more, there's plenty: IS_NULLABLE, NUMERIC_PRECISION, CHARACTER_SET_NAME, etc.

(Not sure I'd use personally use this though, the `is_*` functions usually do enough without an extra database call.  More importantly, info_schema holds the structure of every database on the server, so granting read permissions to it might (should) be a big deal. If you're on a shared host you likely won't have access to it at all.)

MySQL-only alternate: do similar but with [`DESCRIBE [table]`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html). It's pretty explicit though, you'll have to fish out the "bigint" in "bigint(21) unsigned" yourself if that's all you want.

Comment: How can this validate if a specific value is value for a specific data type? This only returns the data type...

Comment: That was more in reaction to reading other responses, not sure I'd have marked it as The Answer.  But with I_S/DESCRIBE you can at least check what's coming from the database, just not the what's going in.  Personally I think the input side would be a total exercise in futility as long as char / varchar / text / nvarchar / etc types exist.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't as simple as it seems, your `is_MEDIUMINT()` function could easily become:

```
is_MEDIUMINT()
is_MEDIUMINT_NULL()
is_MEDIUMINT_NOTNULL()
is_MEDIUMINT_UNSIGNED()
is_MEDIUMINT_UNSIGNED_NULL()
is_MEDIUMINT_UNSIGNED_NOTNULL()
```

Then you run into the problem of different databases types, SQLite for instance has only one `INT` type while MySQL has at least 5 (`TINYINT`, `SMALLINT`, `MEDIUMINT`, `INT`, `BIGINT`), not counting aliases (such as `INTEGER`, `BOOL`, `BOOLEAN` and `SERIAL`) and float types - which would be even harder to implement due to the variable precision argument. Bare in mind that I'm still ignoring several crucial features such as `UNIQUE` and Foreign Key Constrains which could only be validated on the DB.

I don't understand why you think such functions would be useful, because if you could set up your database to work in strict mode and then simply try to insert the values, if the query fails you know something is wrong, quoting the MySQL Manual:

> In **nonstrict mode**, when an
>   out-of-range value is assigned to an
>   integer column, MySQL stores the value
>   representing the corresponding
>   endpoint of the column data type
>   range. If you store 256 into a TINYINT
>   or TINYINT UNSIGNED column, MySQL
>   stores 127 or 255, respectively.

What you be the point of validating the value prior to insertion anyway?

```
if (is_MEDIUMINT($var)) {
  $this->db->insert($anothervar);
}

else {
  // do what?
}
```

If you're trying to avoid errors run the query in a transaction or use the `INSERT OR IGNORE` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Throw it into the database and see if it returns errors. If it doesn't, you types are good enough.

This also means that the dbms you are using will handle the valiation, which means you don't have to update all your validation functions when they decide to change theirs on a whim. And you will most likely not notice this until everything dies and you can't work out why. The less code you have to maintain yourself, the easier your life is :)

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know.
You could, of course, create your own functions or class to do this, based on the rules of your specific database type.

Sorry I can't be more help. (And happy to be educated by any other users if there is a class/functions out there.)

Comment: Thanks Lucanos. Of course, i can wrote some lines to do this, but I'll assume that I'm not the first one to need this :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for the `is_*` functions in PHP?

[is_integer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-integer.php), [is_float](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) etc. ?

There is also [get_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php), but it shouldn't be used for type checking